# Updating database gives "The multi-part identifier could not be bound." Error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update the BookingID in the CounselorDB table. It's previously `null`. cID is a String that contains the predefined CounselorID.

The error I'm getting is the multi-part identifier "x" could not be bound; x being the cID.

Thank you.

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        String sql = string.Format("UPDATE CounselorDB SET BookingID = @BookingID WHERE CounselorID = " + cID);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookingID", getBookingID());
        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: You should parameterise that value too.

Comment: Still gave the same error

Comment: what are the values of getBookingID() and cID?

Comment: getBookingID returns an integer. It goes into the table and give the last used value +1.
cID is a String read in from another table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just try this:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    String sql = "UPDATE CounselorDB "+
                 "SET BookingID = @BookingID "+
                 "WHERE CounselorID = @CounselorID";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookingID", getBookingID());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CounselorID", cID);
    connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: That gave "Invalid column name 'cID'."?

Comment: SInce `cID` contains the value of the `CounselorID`, I don't see where is the problem. I mean why `cID` has to be associated with a column name? It is the value of the parameter `@CounselorID`. Isn't i?

Comment: Ya I have another method set up reading in a random CounselorID from a different table (CounselorDB) but the values are the same.